# Make Numpy.where stop after first true encountered

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I am trying to scaling up a piece of code in terms of input size, the bottleneck seems to be call of a `numpy.where` for which I am only using the first true index:

```
indexs = [numpy.where(_<cump)[0][0] for _ in numpy.random.rand(sample_size)]
```

It would me much faster if I could tell `numpy` to stop after encountering first `true` value (I am inverting a cumulative density function - cump - which grows quickly over the first array values of cump). I could do it by hand with a loop and a break but I was wondering if there was a pythonista way of doing so?

Comment: Are you complaining about `where` stopping too soon, or that it doesn't stop soon enough?  Your title sounds like the former.

Comment: @hpaulj: I am `complaining' about `numpy.where` not stopping soon enough. Indeed, the title was misleading, thanks for pointing it out, updated now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cump` is a cumulative density function then it is monotonic, hence sorted. Rather than linearly scanning it, you are going to get best performance guarantees by binary searching it.

First we create some fake data to search over:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> cump = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(11))
>>> cump -= cump[0]
>>> cump /= cump[-1]
>>> cump
array([ 0.        ,  0.07570573,  0.1417473 ,  0.30536346,  0.36277835,
        0.47102093,  0.54456142,  0.6859625 ,  0.75270741,  0.84691162,  1.
   ])
```

Then we create some fake data to search for:

```
>>> sample = np.random.rand(5)
>>> sample
array([ 0.19597276,  0.37885803,  0.2096784 ,  0.57559965,  0.72175056])
```

And we finally search for it (and find it!):

```
>>> [np.where(_ < cump)[0][0] for _ in sample]
[3, 5, 3, 7, 8]
>>> np.searchsorted(cump, sample)
array([3, 5, 3, 7, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Many thanks this is wonderful, did not now about `searchsorted`, definitely relevant here!!